# link list insert() print();

Tags: c++, list, printing, insert

I am beginner and I have created link list, but my code is not working correctly. plz help thx in advance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace ::std;

class node{
public:

    int data;
    node *link;
};


class linklist{
private:
    node *head=NULL;
    node *tail;
    node *temp;
public:
    // I think there is some issue but it seems perfect to me plz help 
    void insert(int n)
    {

        if(head==NULL)
        {
        tail=new node;
        tail->data=n;
        tail->link=NULL;
        head=tail;
        temp=tail;

        }
        else
        {
            tail=new node;
            tail->data=n;
            tail->link=NULL;
            temp->link=tail;


        }
    }
    void print()
    {
        while(head->link==NULL)
        {
            cout<<head->data<<endl;
            head=head->link;
        }

    }

};

int main() {
    linklist s;
    cout<<"how many numbers you want to enter"<<endl;
    int n,l;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"enter nummber";

        cin>>l;
        s.insert(l);
        s.print();
    }

   }
```

After printing section printing is not doing and it keep printing current element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code.

1. `print` function changes `head` value every time, you need to use local variable. Also your condition for `while` loop is wrong.

   ```
   void print()
   {
      node* t = head;
      while(t->link!=NULL)
      {
         cout<<t->data<<endl;
         t=t->link;
      }
   }
   ```
2. You don't change `temp` when adding new nodes.

   ```
   else
   {
       tail=new node;
       tail->data=n;
       tail->link=NULL;
       temp->link=tail;
       temp = tail; // here
   }
   ```